# Which Stack Exchange site is for asking about problems with Facebook accounts?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask question about problems in my Facebook account. On which Stack Exchange site should I ask?

Comment: Pretty broad. If you have questions about *using* Facebook you could head over to [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/). Sounds more like you need Facebook Support though.

Comment: Related: [On which Stack Exchange site can I ask customer service questions about product X or company Y?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347991/295232)

Comment: I have the exact same question, currently about understanding why Facebook censor my blog related to math popularization (about everyday bias related to that, and fitting none of the "out of our standards" topics), and what can/should I do about that.
In the past, I often had questions about stuck situations, like how to signal a phishing post that manage to undisplay signaling button.
"contacting Facebook" is near-impossible, while expert community has some technical knowledge of how to. 
→ We do need a place for that, and it's technical based.

Comment: ( Beside, Facebook is no longer "just a product": it happens to be a part of the web where it's often impossible not to be (when you need to reach a large bunch of peoples that are already around)).

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET Are you still interested in questions about Facebook?

Comment: @Rubén : not at this very moment but it can happen again; why ?

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET [facebook] is the 3rd popular tag in [webapps.se] . We need some help voting and answering those questions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Questions about *using* Facebook are on-topic for [Web Applications SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Web Applications Stack Exchange** is for expert and advanced users of web applications.
>
> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, **Facebook**, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application

Do study the site [help center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to see what is on and off-topic.

If you have a Facebook *support issue*, you'll need to contact Facebook directly. Web Applications SE can help you make sense of the features Facebook offers (e.g. *how do I prevent my photos from being seen by anyone but my friends?*), they cannot fix broken accounts.

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)

Comment: Check out the Web Applications FAQ. Start with [What kind of questions can I ask here? The detailed version](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/894/311306)

Answer (score 11):

If you've got problems with your account then you need to be talking to Facebook support, not some Q&A site on the internet.

Comment: Facebook support is horrible and their documentation is almost as bad. If you want to solve a Facebook problem 99% of the time you find the answer on a blog or forum, so why not a SE?

Comment: @jerclarke Most requests for help with Facebook account issues can't get a definitive answer from the community as it's defined in SO/SE. Instead of being posted as a SO/SE question, people looking for help with these issues might use the chat, but first, they should find an expert willing to participate. Web Applications chat very rarely has active users. Despite that, it's not an option for brand-new users. Ref. [On which Stack Exchange site can I ask customer service questions about product X or company Y?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347991/295232)

Answer (score 3):

I have noticed that several questions asked here about Facebook have marked as duplicate of this question and that the previous answers might have not addressed completely the concerns.

First, regarding the problems with a Facebook account, this is way too broad. As suggested in both previous answers, in general terms, users should contact Facebook support. Start looking at https://www.facebook.com/help/.

Related:

- [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/1595451)
- [On which Stack Exchange site can I ask customer service questions about product X or company Y?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347991/289691)

Other questions:

- Questions about using the Facebook's web app as end-user might be on-topic in [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com). The exceptions are questions about interactions between users (or the lack of interaction) , troubleshooting like questions, specialized advertising / commercial (how to sell more / how to manage budget), questions asking about internal policies, technologies or any stuff that only Facebook employees can answer. [[facebook] info](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/facebook/info) 3,223 questions.
- Questions about using Facebook's apps for Android might be on topic in [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com). [[facebook] info](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/facebook/info) 281 questions.
- Questions about Facebook's apps related to Apple devices like device privacy and app permissions, might be asked in [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com). [[facebook] info](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/facebook/info) 237 questions
- Questions about integrating Facebook using their API's as programmer might be on topic in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) but also might be on topic in other sites depenting on the system to be integreated. SO [[facebook] info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook/info) 85,745 questions.

The following searches might help to explore posts across all the Stack Exchange Network having `[facebook]`:

- [[facebook]](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfacebook%5D)  205,698 results.
- [[facebook] is:question isanswered:1](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfacebook%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20isanswered%3A1) 44,516 results (only answered questions).
- [[facebook] is:question isanswered:0](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfacebook%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20isanswered%3A0) 48,004 results (only unanswered questions).

---

- Arqade [[facebook]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook/info) 18 questions.
- Ask Ubuntu [[facebook]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/facebook/info) 199 questions.
- Information Security [[facebook]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook/info) 264 questions.
- Code Review [[facebook]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/facebook/info) 41 questions.
- Game Developement [[facebook]](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook/info) 92 questions.
- Magento [[facebook]](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook/info) 79 questions.
- Salesforce [[facebook]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/facebook/info) 65 questions.
- Software Engineering [[facebook]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook/info) 34 questions
- Software Recommendations [[facebook]](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook/info) 80 questions
- Stack Overflow Spanish [[facebook]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook/info) 148 questions.
- Stack Overflow Japanese [[facebook]](https://jp.stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook/info) 44 questions.
- Stack Overflow Portuguese [[facebook]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook/info) 308 questions.
- Stack Overflow Russian [[facebook]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook/info) 228 questions.
- Super User [[facebook]](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/facebook/info) 226 questions.
- User Experience [[facebook]](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook/info) 96 questions.
- Webmasters [[facebook]](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/facebook/info) 427 questions.

---

- Cross Validated [[social-network] facebook](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsocial-network%5D+facebook) 18 results.
- Freelancing [facebook](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/search?q=facebook) 77 results.
- Interpersonal Skills [[social-media] facebook](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsocial-media%5D+facebook) 45 results.
- Mathematica and Wolfram Language [[social-media] facebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsocial-media%5D+facebook) 23 results.
- Personal Finance and Money [facebook](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=facebook) 304 results.
- Psychology and Neuroscience [[social-network] facebook](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsocial-networks%5D+facebook) 13 results.
- The Workplace [[social-media] facebook](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsocial-media%5D+facebook) 94 results.
- Writing [facebook](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=facebook) 217 results.