# Stack Exchange site to ask Google Help Communities questions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

We [read](https://support.google.com/communities/answer/7424249)

> The Google Help Communities are a place for Google users to ask questions or provide feedback about Google products and services, discuss products and services with other Google users and enthusiasts, provide tips for using Google products and services to the community, get help from other users and Google enthusiasts on all of the above.

And they are great. There's

- https://support.google.com/maps/community
- https://support.google.com/meet/community
- ...tons of them. Even:
- https://support.google.com/communities

(But there is no place to ask questions in the latter.)
Yes, "Just write to Google. There's even a Feedback button!"

But, let's say one wanted to post a question, a single question that pertained to all the Communities at once, but wanted to, in addition to writing to Google, also ask it on Stack Exchange. Which Stack Exchange site is the right site to ask it on?

Comment: What type of question? Could you give an example title?

Comment: I was very careful not to mention any possible specific question examples, as that would immediately cause my question to go into a tailspin. But you are welcome to add your own examples though!

Comment: Not even a little detail? Without more information we would be guessing. The SE site that would accept questions about how to use the Google Help Communities API is different from the site that would accept questions about how to format there, and many questions (e.g. about site policies) have no place on SE that will accept them.

Comment: Need more focus, should focus on just one problem. The Google services platform encompasses a wide variety of IT products and services ranging from maps, translators, search engines, programming languages and frameworks, network infrastructure services, cloud storage services, ISP, robotics, medical research, physics studies, astronomy studies, .................................each subject must be dealt with on the respective site of the Stack Exchange Network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At https://stackexchange.com/sites you will find the complete list of SE sites showing the site name and a very brief description of each of them. Below are some examples:

[Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)

> Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators

If you are interested in the Google Product Experts (GPE) program, GPEs at certain point have moderator like-responsibilities in Google Product Communities (GPC).

[Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/tour) (CSE)

> Q&A for those involved in the field of teaching Computer Science

There a lot of Google products that might be used by CSE and students and that are related to computer science. It's very likely that there are questions that could be asked related to Google products as the subjects of study as well as tools. Also there are programs, grants, events, etc. that might be source of questions and answers.

[Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour) (CS)

> Q&A for students, researchers and practitioners of computer science

Google is what is thanks to CS. There are a humongous variety of stuff related to this.

Please be open to the possibility that there might not be a place in the GPC and in the Stack Exchange sites for the question that you want to post.

If you want to complain about this directly to Google, go to https://google.com/contact.

If you want to complain about this directly to Stack Overflow Inc., go to https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact.

But let’s be positive and say that you find a site. Maybe

[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)

> Q&A for power users of web applications

Before asking a question on this site, please take [the tour](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). On it you will find a link to [What kind of questions can I ask here? The detailed version](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/894/88163). Briefly, in Web Applications, you might ask a question about **using** any of the GPC. Questions about the GPE program, GPC content, policies, technologies, disputes among other stuff not directly related to using GPCs as web applications, are off-topic. Also troubleshooting like questions are off-topic.

Related

- [On which Stack Exchange site can I ask customer service questions about product X or company Y?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347991/289691)

Comment: It looks like I need to first ask, "What Stack Exchange do I ask about when https://about.google/contact-google/ comes up in the wrong language, and there is no language switcher button on it?" But I better quit while I'm ahead.

Comment: All the Help Communities use the same email system, that either notifies one of their own activities too, or none at all. I was wondering how to make it only notify when someone replies to a post. Not also when I create a post, which of course I already know about.

Comment: @DanJacobson A question about how to set the email notifications of GPC might be asked in Web Applications. Also a question about how to set Gmail filters could be asked in Web Applications. Search the site thoroughly and the respective help centers first :)