# When assisting with software navigation, what is the best way to differentiate between a question and a support request?

Tags: discussion, help

All the sites that include questions about software applications in their scope have the same situation frequently seen in Web Applications Stack Exchange; people post a request asking for help solving a problem.

For example, on Web Applications Stack Exchange, there are a lot of questions asking for help to solve a broad range of problems; most of them are beyond the scope of the site or aren't a good fit for the question-and-answer model as they look to require a lot of back and forth.

One type of question beyond the webapps.se scope is asking for guidance on doing a task described at a high level, like how to send many emails using a public emails service like Gmail and Outlook.com, without clearly defining a specific problem about using a web application. The answer to this kind of question requires a lengthy answer and making a lot of suppositions; there is a high probability that the OP if they aren't a "hit and run" user, might ask to tailor the answer to needs that they usually aren't able to specify without expert guidance.

Another type of this kind of question, that appears very frequently are Facebook account recovery help requests. Apparently this is a very common problem, and "desperate souls" ask for help everywhere. Even Stack Overflow support gets this kind of request.

[image: Submit a Ticket - Stack Overflow Support]

> I need help with my Facebook account

[image: Submit a Ticket - Stack Overflow Support]

> #### Submit a ticket
>
> Welcome! You can raise a Stack Overflow support request from the options provided. What product are you seeking help with today?
>
> This portal provides support for Stack Overflow and its product. We are not able to provide support for your Facebook account.
> Please visit the Facebook Help Center for assistance.

Telling users that, let's say, a question asking for help to recover a Facebook page used for business is off-topic, without providing further guidance, might be perceived as **unfriendly** and **unkind**.

How do sites with a scope encompassing software applications handle help requests **in a friendly and kind way**? Is it a good idea to have a FAQ using similar wording to the one used on the above screenshots on [per-site-metas](/questions/tagged/per-site-metas)?

#### Related

- [Which Stack Exchange site is for asking about problems with Facebook accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243644/1359324)

Comment: Downvote and vote/flag to close. It's not unfriendly or unkind. It's how Stack Exchange works to rate content and handle questions which are off-topic. If you want, you could leave them a comment telling them more specifically where they can receive help (which is exactly what happens on the SE support portal when you click the "I need help with my Facebook account" button).

Comment: Your title appears generic, but your question text appears to be primarily focused on Facebook account support requests. I think that you're intending to have this be generic, but it would be helpful to make that clearer in the first portions of your question.

Comment: You say "people post a request asking for help solving a problem". Doesn't that describe nearly *every* question? It would be helpful if what you were meaning there was clarified as to how you're attempting to differentiate what you're asking about from all questions.

Comment: If such requests for customer support are a substantial issue for a particular site, the site could create a community-specific close reason which is explicitly about customer-support requests being off-topic. That close reason could have "kind" wording explaining to the user that it's *not possible* to get such support here and directing them to go to the official support site for the website/company with which they have a problem. If you really need more room than is available in the closed notice, then the closed banner could point to a FAQ.

Comment: Are you asking this from the point of view of an individual on such a site (e.g. voting, voting to close, comments), or how the site might be set up to handle these (e.g. create new/additional site-specific close reasons)?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback. I apologize for not being able to address all the points you mentioned in your comments at this time. However, I have made an edit to the question to clarify that it is a generic one. I added a type of question that is typically found in web applications and is very likely to be present in sites like Stack Overflow and Super User, as well as other sites that allow questions related to software.  I'll be back a bit later to address more of the shared concerns.

Answer (score 3):

> what is the best way to differentiate between a question and a support request?

All that matters is whether is on-topic for the site according to the site's Help Center and Meta consensus. If it is, then the question should stay.

**Consult your site's `/help/on-topic` page, and your main site's meta site.**

For example,

- On Stack Overflow, see the "Good Custom Closure Reasons" section of [the "Custom Close Reasons" guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417484/11107541).
- Super User's `/help/on-topic` says: "*[question is] not about … issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,*"

Off-topic posts should be closed. It may be needed to use the custom close-reason option for these. Your site meta might have suggestions for template messages to use.

---

> Telling users that, let's say, a question asking for help to recover a Facebook page used for business is off-topic, without providing further guidance, might be perceived as unfriendly and unkind.

"We're not able to help you with this problem of yours / This question is not on-topic here. See also <meta discussion / Help Center link>. You should seek the correct avenue for support with this problem."

^ What's so unfriendly or unkind about that? Honestly, I think someone who thinks that's unfriendly or unkind is being unreasonable.

In fact, an argument could be made about site-*etiquette* that if the asker didn't care to read about the topicality of the site, *they're* the ones being discourteous. (okay- not that I actually would hold something like that against someone. I'd give them the benefit of the doubt- at least for the first time)

Also, I'm not aware of any community consensus or rules from the company that we have to be "friendly" with other users. The Code of Conduct lays out that all users are expected to be *kind* to one another, but as far as I know, *friendliness* is not a requirement. There *is* a comment-flag reason "unfriendly or unkind". I.e. You mustn't be *unfriendly* in your comments.

See also [What about the community is "toxic" to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342779/997587)

---

> How do sites having a scope that encompasses software applications handle help requests in a friendly and kind way?

If you want to be particularly friendly and kind, you can take the sentence I wrote above, and adapt it to something like "Hi <username>! Sorry, but we're not able to help you with this problem of yours / this question is not on-topic here. See <meta discussion / Help Center link> for why. Please use the correct avenue for support with this problem." And if you want to go an extra mile, link them to the right place to ask for help.

As I stated above, you don't need to put these decorations / cherries-on-top to be friendly and kind. It's up to you how extra you want to go with this. I personally used to try, and now I'm somewhere in between (maybe falling towards the curt side).

---

This next info isn't super related here, since off-topic question should be closed (often with custom close-reasons), but on the general topic of giving the same guidance over and over, it helps prevent messenger-fatigue if you have tools to help with pasting these kinds of common messages. Here are some tools that help with *comments* (not with custom close-reasons):

- [Can we have some site approved canned comments to match the new CoC and welcoming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371410/11107541)
- [Make your own custom "magic links" for comments!](https://stackapps.com/q/6650/99652)
- [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/99652)
- [Comment Templates Context Menu, an auto-comments user script](https://stackapps.com/q/9426/99652)
- [QuickComment2: Automatic keyboard-only comment snippets](https://stackapps.com/q/6167/99652)
- [QuickComment: comment shortcuts to cut down on tedium](https://stackapps.com/q/4796/99652)

---

Also related on the topic of Facebook questions: [Which Stack Exchange site is for asking about problems with Facebook accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243644/997587)